# Bookshelf.js: how to define cross-relations?

Tags: node.js, relation, bookshelf.js

How can i define hasMany Space -> Accounts relation?

```
var Space = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'spaces',
    // Account variable does not exist :/
});

var Account = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'accounts',
    spaceId   : function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Space);
    },
});
```

What is the correct way to define this?

P.S. There is no tag for bookshelf js library: http://bookshelfjs.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-hasMany), this should work:

```
    var Account = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName : 'accounts'
    });

    var Space = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName : 'spaces',
        accounts  : function() {
            return this.hasMany(Account, 'spaceId'); // spaceId is foreign key for Account table
        }
    });
```